# Rails 4.1 secrets.yml error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Just upgraded to Rails 4.1 and am using `secrets.yml`.

This is what it looks like:

```
development:
    secret_key_base: akshdakjshdgakjhsdgakjdhgaskjdhgaskjdhgska

test:
    secret_key_base: somelegitlongasskeygeneratedbyrakesecrethere    
production:
    secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

When I restart my server and visit any page, in my browser I get an "Internal Server Error".

In my log file, I see this:

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Unexpected error while processing request: (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 14 column 1
    /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse'
    /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
    /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
    /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:15:in `load_with_options'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:313:in `secrets'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:439:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:195:in `env_config'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    bin/rails:4:in `require'
    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Unexpected error while processing request: (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 14 column 1
    /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse'
    /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
    /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
    /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:15:in `load_with_options'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:313:in `secrets'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:439:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:195:in `env_config'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@my_project/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    bin/rails:4:in `require'
    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

I tried multiple iterations of the secrets.yml file, to even enclose the `secret_key_base` in single quotations like `'somelongasskeyhere'` but that didn't work.

**Update 1**

So it seems the issue may be with how finnicky YAML is. I think it has something to do with the spacing & tabs I put in, but I just can't seem to get it perfect. Now I am getting another error at a different position in the line.

After re-doing some of the spaces to just use the spacebar 4 times, versus the tab - which was set at 4 spaces, I am now getting a different error:

```
Unexpected error while processing request: (<unknown>): found a tab character that violate intendation while scanning a plain scalar at line 13 column 3
```

Which references this line:

```
development:
  secret_key_base:'86bc42f97803818b48ff88ef15d9d4df6b6b4e4e723c119967a29751de33b5687af3a57542b4a8364cb3d6b51a872ad1188b9de6f0faab578272451aa798956c'
```

**Update 2**

It definitely is something to do with my spacing, because once I copied and pasted this file - https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise/blob/master/config/secrets.yml - into mine and just replaced the key_base with mine, everything worked just fine.

Comment: I had the same exact error too. Removing all spaces and newline characters and putting them back in solved the problem!

Comment: Had the same problem. Initially I had 1 tab before "secret_key_base:", now I have 2 spaces. Workes now.